# AllenNLP DatasetReader: only loads a single instance, instead of iterating over all instances in the training dataset

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, allennlp

I am using **AllenNLP** to train a hierarchical **attention network model**. My training dataset consists of a list of **JSON objects** (eg, each object in the list is a **JSON object** with keys := ["text", "label"]. The value associated with the text key is a list of lists, eg:

```
[{"text":[["i", "feel", "sad"], ["not", "sure", "i", "guess", "the", "weather"]], "label":0} ... {"text":[[str]], "label":int}]
```

My DatasetReader class looks like:

```
@DatasetReader.register("my_reader")
class TranscriptDataReader(DatasetReader):
    def __init__(self,
                 token_indexers: Optional[Dict[str, TokenIndexer]] = None,
                 lazy: bool = True) -> None:
        super().__init__(lazy)
        self._token_indexers = token_indexers or {'tokens': SingleIdTokenIndexer()}

    def _read(self, file_path: str) -> Iterator[Instance]:
        with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
            data = json.loads(f.read())
            for _,data_json in enumerate(data):
                sent_list = []
                for segment in data_json["text"]:
                    sent_list.append(self.get_text_field(segment))
                yield self.create_instance(sent_list, str(data_json["label"]))

    def get_text_field(self, segment):
        return TextField([Token(token.lower()) for token in segment],self._token_indexers)


    def create_instance(self, sent_list, label):
        label_field = LabelField(label, skip_indexing=False)
        fields = {'tokens': ListField(sent_list), 'label': label_field}
        return Instance(fields)
```

and in my config file, I have:

```
{
  dataset_reader: {
    type: 'my_reader',
  },

  train_data_path: 'data/train.json',
  validation_data_path: 'data/dev.json',

 data_loader: {
    batch_sampler: {
      type: 'bucket',
      batch_size: 10
    }
 },
```

I have tried (alternatively) setting the `lazy` param for the dataset reader to `True` and `False`.

- When set to `True`, the model is able to train, however, I observe that only one train and one dev instance actually get loaded, when my dataset contains ~100.
- When set to `False`, I've modified the `yield` line in `_read` to be `return`; however, this causes a type error in the base vocabulary class. I've also tried keeping the `yield` as is when set to `False`; in this case, no instances get loaded at all, and since the set of instances is empty, the vocabulary does not get instantiated, and the embedding class throws an error.

Would appreciate pointers, and/or tips for debugging.

Comment: What version of AllenNLP are you using? Since 2.0, dataset readers are always lazy, so this distinction no longer appears.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `allennlp>=v2.0.0`, the `lazy` parameter in the `DatasetReader` constructor is deprecated. Therefore, your `super().__init__(lazy)` would be instead interpreted as the new constructor parameter `max_instances`, i.e. `max_instances=True` which is equivalent to `max_instances=1`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you print and tell us how many instances are getting loaded after reading the json file (added a print command below for clarity)

```
def _read(self, file_path: str) -> Iterator[Instance]:
        with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
            data = json.loads(f.read())
            print(len(data))
            for _,data_json in enumerate(data):
               sent_list = []
                for segment in data_json["text"]:
                    sent_list.append(self.get_text_field(segment))
                yield self.create_instance(sent_list, str(data_json["label"]))
```